# R webscraping: interrogating for date

Tags: r

I am able to webscrape a table from a webpage containing news

```
library(XML)
webpage  <- "http://www.tradingeconomics.com/calendar"
tables <- readHTMLTable(webpage )
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))

dfcal <- as.data.frame(tables$calendar)
```

For example how could I webscrape news from  Jan 2014? 
I am able to do this on the webpage by altering button settings, but how can I do it from within R?

Also are there better ways for collecting economic news from within R? 
I have looked on http://www.rseek.org/ but could not find anything.
Thank you for your help.

```
 <form method="post" action="/calendar" id="aspnetForm">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" 


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You should use send a POST request. something like `library(Rcurl); doc <- postForm("http://www.tradingeconomics.com/china/calendar",
                startDate="2014-01-22",...); readHTmlTable(doc))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) noted you can manipulate a browser with RSelenium and Selenium:

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open(); Sys.sleep(15);
remDr$navigate("http://www.tradingeconomics.com/calendar")
# get the DOM element for the custom date
webElem <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//a[@data-target=\"#datesDiv\"]")
# send a click to the element using javascript
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].click();", list(webElem))
startDate <- remDr$findElement("id", "startDate")
startDate$clearElement()
startDate$sendKeysToElement(list("2014-01-01"))
endDate <- remDr$findElement("id", "endDate")
endDate$clearElement()
endDate$sendKeysToElement(list("2014-01-31"))

okButton <- remDr$findElement("id", "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl02_Button2")
okButton$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(15)
wData <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

require(XML)
tables <- readHTMLTable(wData)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
dfcal <- as.data.frame(tables$calendar)
```

The above script opens the webpage. Clicks the custom date. Enters the relevant dates and clicks the ok button.
The html source of the page is then taken.

Answer (score 1):

I did an intercept of the request (it's at the bottom of this "answer"). It's a fairly ugly AJAX call since it looks like (I didn't read the page javascript) it base64 encodes something called the "view state". There's also a cookie it passed which may or may not be important. Of the following parameters, I have no idea which ones actually are required, but you can see all the HTTP request headers and query parameters sent. Try playing with them in a POST as [@agstudy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838509/agstudy) suggested.

Another option is to use [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) to drive the browser and scrape that way.

---

**HTTP AJAX request intercept below:**

```
POST /calendar HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tradingeconomics.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://www.tradingeconomics.com/calendar
Content-Length: 116721
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=k2tc0xaqplgnps01mleehdcw; _ga=GA1.2.721625302.1402653647
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache

ctl00%24AjaxScriptManager1%24ScriptManager1=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24UpdatePanel1%7Cctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24Button2&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=GIANT_BASE64_STRING_THAT_I_REMOVED&srch-term=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24startDate=2014-01-01&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24endDate=2014-01-31&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24DropDownListTimezone=-300&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24Country=top&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24Category=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24Importance=&__ASYNCPOST=true&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctl02%24Button2=ok
```